# Share Facebook or Line with onclick function, but get SEO problem "Links are not crawlable"

Tags: accessibility, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I share Facebook and Line with onclick function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='.concat(encodeURIComponent(location.href)), '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,height=700,width=550')" title="Facebook Share" aria-label="Facebook Share">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('http://line.naver.jp/R/msg/text/?Page title%0A'.concat(encodeURIComponent(location.href)),'Share with Line', config='height=700,width=550')" title="Line Share" aria-label="Line Share">
```

Google Lighthouse result:

> Search engines may use `href` attributes on links to crawl websites. Ensure that the `href` attribute of anchor elements links to an appropriate destination, so more pages of the site can be discovered.

So I couldn't use `<a>` element, if want to open link with new window?

Comment: removed the SEO tag as people just close questions with that tag blindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case I would say you *could* ignore that message, you are using the correct element from a semantics perspective.

However one way you could improve this (and remove the error) is to have the URL prebuilt on the server and then use a JavaScript listener to intercept the click and open your new window.

**The big advantage** of this is that you have a valid URL **when** your JavaScript fails and it is also better for SEO.

In the below example I have moved the URL, window name and window settings into `data` attributes on the link.

I then put the full URL into the `href` attribute without all the window settings etc.

Finally I attach an event handler to your links that intercepts the click and instead launches the window.

**Please note you cannot run the below snippet due to sandbox on Stack Overflow so [check this fiddle instead.](https://jsfiddle.net/u9hgatLk/)**

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.sharer');

for(var z = 0; z < anchors.length; z++) {

anchors[z].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
//stop the default click action
  e.preventDefault();
// grab the base sharing URL
  var URL = e.target.getAttribute('data-url');
// grab the name we want to give the window (parameter 2 on window.open)
  var windowName = e.target.getAttribute('data-windowName');
// Grab parameter 3 for window.oprn (window settings)
  var windowSettings = e.target.getAttribute('data-settings');
// call window.open
  window.open(URL + window.location.href, windowName, windowSettings);
}, false);

}
```

```html
<h2>Won't work on Stack Overflow due to sandbox so may need tweaking your side</h2>

<a class="sharer" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640807/share-facebook-or-line-with-onclick-function-but-get-seo-problem-links-are-not" data-url="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=" data-windowName="" data-settings="menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,height=700,width=550" title="Facebook Share" aria-label="Facebook Share">Facebook</a>

<a class="sharer" href="http://line.naver.jp/R/msg/text/?Page title%0Ahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640807/share-facebook-or-line-with-onclick-function-but-get-seo-problem-links-are-not" data-url="http://line.naver.jp/R/msg/text/?Page title%0A" data-windowName="Share with Line"  data-settings="height=700,width=550" title="Line Share" aria-label="Line Share">Line</a>

<h2>fallback behaviour</h2>
<p>The below shows how the link behaves with no javascript</p>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640807/share-facebook-or-line-with-onclick-function-but-get-seo-problem-links-are-not" title="Facebook Share" aria-label="Facebook Share" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```